# VS 2017 basic web project template

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, web, visual-studio-2017

I am currently struggling to find a basic project template for a simple angular app that I am building in VS 2017. This app will consist of only html/js/typescript files, npm's package.json file and a gulpfile. All templates I'm finding are for class libraries or include other aspects of server side based projects that I don't want or need in my project.

Is there a way to make a basic web project in VS 2017? I'd like to stick with Visual Studio since it is the IDE we use for our other projects.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to work on Angular I will suggest you to use visual studio code. To create a basic structure of an angular app use angular-cli.
First you need to install angular cli. Follow this link to install cli : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to create a new Angular project is to use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io) it builds the skeleton of the project including build/ transpilation tools. It will create a lot of the boiler-plate code for you too, e.g. adding a new module can be done from the cli.

I'd suggest looking at other IDEs such as Sublime Text, VS code etc. but if you must integrate with VS 2017, there are resources available, such as [angular cli and vs2017](https://candordeveloper.com/2017/04/12/how-to-use-angular-cli-with-visual-studio-2017/).